# strange HashMap.put() behaviour

Tags: java, hashmap

I am attempting to troubleshoot an intermittent failure that appears to be related to removing an object from a HashMap and then putting that same object back using a new key.  My HashMap is created as follows:

```
transactions = new HashMap<Short, TransactionBase>();
```

The code that does the re-assignment is as follows:

```
transactions.remove(transaction.tran_no);
transaction.tran_no = generate_transaction_id();
transactions.put(transaction.tran_no, transaction);
```

The intermittent behaviour that I am seeing is that code that executes immediately after this that depends upon the transaction object being locatable does not appear to find the transaction object using the new transaction id.  However, at some future point, the transaction can be located.  So pulling at straws, is there any sort of asynchronous effect to put() or remove that can cause this sort of behaviour?

I should mention that, to the best of my knowledge, the container is being accessed by only one thread.  I have already read in he documentation that class HashMap is not "synchronised".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no "asynchronous" effects in the HashMap class.  As soon as you put something in there, it's there.  You should double- and triple- check to make sure that there are no threading issues.

The only other thing I can think of is that you're making a copy of the HashMap somewhere.  The copy obviously won't be affected by you adding stuff into the original, or vice versa.

Answer (score 7):

There is a slight difference between remove/get and put (although my guess is that you have a threading issue).

The parameter for `remove`/`get` is of type `Object`; for `put` it is of type `K`. The reason for that has been stated many times before. This means it has problems with boxing. I'm not even going to guess what the rules are. If a value gets boxed as a `Byte` in one place and a `Short` in another, then those two objects cannot be equal.

There is a similar issue with `List.remove(int)` and `List.remove(Object)`.

Answer (score 6):

I presume that every time you check for the presence of the item you're definitely using a `short` or `Short argument` to `Map.get()` or `Map.contains()`?

These methods take Object arguments so if you pass them an `int` it will be converted to an `Integer` and will never match any item in your Map because they will all have `Short` keys.

Answer (score 2):

Just one suggestion...you're focusing on accesses to the HashMap but I wonder if you should also see if your generate_transaction_id() is thread safe or if it is behaving in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 2):

Have you overridden `equals()` but not `hashCode()` in your model objects?  How about `compareTo()` ? If you get these wrong, Collections will behave strangely indeed.

Check Java Practices on [equals()](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) and [compareTo()](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10).

Comment: The HashMap is using Short as the key, so it shouldn't be an issue, is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you're correct,it shouldn't be a problem if he's using Short as the key.

Answer (score 1):

So you know `HashMap`'s not thread safe. Are you sure it's being accessed by only one thread? After all, intermittent failures a frequently threading related. If not, you can wrap it with [`Collections.synchronizedMap()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)), like so:

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(transactions);
```

You could always just try so you can eliminate that possibility.

It should be pointed out that this just wraps the original map with one with all the methods synchronized. You may want to consider using a synchronized block if the access is localized.

Comment: This won't work because he's performing 3 separate operations on the map.  He needs a synchronized block around all 3 to ensure that they atomic, and then synchronize again in his getter.

Comment: If you use Collections.synchronizedMap() it exposes the lock it uses for internal operations so that you can build these 3-step transactions without having to add extra synchronization for one-step operations.  See the javadoc.

Comment: Can you provide a specific link?  Looking at the source code it looks like the SynchronizedMap class is package private and, even if it wasn't, the mutex it uses isn't exposed anywhere.  This is the Java 1.6 source, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

What does this generate_transaction_id() function do? If it is generating a 16-bit GUID-like thing, you could easily get hash collisions. Combined with threading, you could get:

```
T1: transaction1.tran_no = generate_transaction_id();    => 1729
T2: transaction2.tran_no = generate_transaction_id();    => 1729
T1: transactions.put(transaction1.tran_no, transaction1); => map.put(1729, transaction1)
T2: transactions.put(transaction2.tran_no, transaction2); => map.put(1729, transaction2)
T1: int tran_no = transactions.get(1729);               => transaction2
T1: transactions.remove(transaction.tran_no);           => map.remove(1729)
T2: int tran_no = transactions.get(1729);               => null
```

Of course, this could only be a solution if that 'to the best of your knowledge' part is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Threading has been mentioned in a few responses already, but have you considered the visibility issue for objects used by multiple threads?  It's possible (and quite common) that if you put an object into a collection in one thread, it will not be "published" to other threads unless you have properly synchronized on the collection.

[Threads and Locks](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html)

[Synchronization and thread safety in Java](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_safety.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

As others have observed you HAVE to know whether the HashMap is accessed by just one Thread, or not. **CollectionSpy** is a new profiler that lets you find out instantly, for all containers, how many threads perform any accesses. See [www.collectionspy.com](http://www.collectionspy.com) for more details.